# Where the objective function of Skip-Gram Negative Sampling (SGNS) come from?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec

In the paper of "[Neural Word Embedding as Implicit Matrix Factorization](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2014/file/feab05aa91085b7a8012516bc3533958-Paper.pdf)", there is an objective function for Skip-Gram Negative Sampling. I wanted to know where this formula come from

[image]

Comment: It is described on: https://github.com/a1da4/paper-survey/issues/27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original w2v paper [1] shows the loss function for each pair of target and context words $(w, c)$. The model is a binary classifier that learns to classify "positive samples" from "negative samples".
Each observed $(w,c)$ pair is a positive sample. For each of those, $k$ random context words $c_N$ are sampled from a distribution $P_D(c)$ (e.g. uniformly), giving $k$ negative sample pairs $(w,c_N)$. Overall, the model learns to differentiate context words that $w$ co-occurs with from those it doesn't.

The model has one vector (or *word embedding*) $\overrightarrow{w}$ for each target word $w$ and another $\overrightarrow{c}$ for each context word $c$. Any given word, e.g. "cat", will at various times be considered a target word and at others a context word, and so have 2 embeddings.

The model predicts a word pair $w$, $c$ as being a *positive* sample by Prob$[(w,c)$ +ve$]=\sigma(\overrightarrow{w}\!\cdot\!\overrightarrow{c})$, i.e. the dot product of their embeddings in a *sigmoid* function. By implication, the probability that $w$, $c$ are a *negative* sample is $\ 1\!-\! \sigma(\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{c}) = \sigma(-\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{c})$.

The loss function is maximised for all positive and negative samples as in standard *logistic regression*. $\#(w,c)$ is the number of times the word pair $(w,c)$ occurs. For each occurrence $\sigma(\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{c})$ is maximised (towards 1). For each of the corresponding negative samples $(w, c_N)$, $\sigma(-\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{c_N})$ is maximised, or equivalently $\sigma(\overrightarrow{w}\cdot\overrightarrow{c_N})$ is *minimised* (towards 0).
$k$ appears since there are $k$ negative samples drawn for each positive sample.
The expectation $\mathbb{E}_{c_N\sim P_N}[...]$ appears because each negative sample is drawn from $P_N$. The expectation can instead be written as a weighted sum over all possible context words (as Levy & Goldberg do in their paper).

[1] Mikolov, T., Sutskever, I., Chen, K., Corrado, G., and Dean, J. (2013).  Distributed Representations of Words and Phrases and their Compositionality. In Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems.